# css height 100% of remaining content

Tags: css, height

I know this question has been asked so many times, but I can not find a way to make it work in my particular case.

I have a container div in which there are 2 divs: the first one does not have a particular height and the second should fill the remaining height of the viewport.

My container div css:

```css
.overlay_on {
    display: block !important;
    position:fixed;
    top:40px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color: white;
}
```

The code:

```
<div class="overlay_on">
    <div style="max-width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">some content that can expand</div>
    <div style="min-height:100%;height:100%; width: 100%;">other content that should fill the remaining height and not more</div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the second div is taking the height of the parent and not the remaining height.

How can I fix this?

#### Update:

I created a fiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3MgBx/
What I want is that the second div (in green) fill the remaining height and not more (I putted a beautiful image in it at height 100% to show that the div is continuing below the window)

Comment: The second div is filling the remaining height of the parent. You just don't see it. try tempoarary set `background-color: blue;` for this div, to see it is working.

Comment: The image has the height of the div that is in. "Div is continuing below the window"? What does it mean? If you want to set the margin to the bottom edge of the browser, you can set margin-bottom property for the div with .overlay_on class.

Comment: in the example the bottom of the image is cropped - this shows that the green div does not fill the remaining height but more.

Comment: This is possible browser issue, as different browsers have different default margins. I had this problem with a table that didn't display the margin inside the browser window.. Try to change the .overlay_on height from 100% to 99%. It should solve your problem.

Comment: i want to see the image completely

Comment: 99% not solved anything - the problem is that the green div is taking 100% of the browser window height and should take 100% of the remaining space between the red div and the bottom of the window

Comment: i fixed it using javascript calculation to get the remaining height...

Comment: Can you post your solution, as an answer, so this question could be helpful for someone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i'm answering myself :

the solution i found is doing calculation to find the percentage of the remaining height (and redoing it on window resize)

HTML

```
<div class="overlay_on">
<div id="bandeau-proj">some content that can expand - some content that can expand - some content that can expand - some content that can expand some content that can expand - some content that can expand - some content that can expand - some content that can expand - </div>
    <div id="slider-cont"><img src="http://wallpaper.metalship.org/images/immortal9.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay_on { 
display: block !important;
position:fixed;
top:40px;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
min-height: 100%;
z-index:1000;
background-color: red;
}
#bandeau-proj{
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
#slider-cont{
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00FF00;

}

img{height:100%;}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var top =  jQuery('#bandeau-proj').offset().top;
var hauteur =  jQuery('#bandeau-proj').outerHeight();
var ySlider = top+hauteur;
var WH = jQuery(window).height();
var available_percent = 100-((ySlider*100)/WH);

jQuery("#slider-cont").css('height',available_percent+'%');
```

and the FIDDLE EXAMPLE :
http://jsfiddle.net/2vu9x/1/

Comment: this question can be useful why -1?